# Adding Height to another Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm adding 50px on every click on my div header, and i want to make my div main has the same height of header when header is bigger than it.

I don't know why its not working.

I have this script

```
$(function () {
    var alturaHeader = $('header').height();
    var alturaMain = $('.main').height();

    $('button').click(function(){
        $('header').height(function(index, height){
            return (height + 50);
        });

        console.log(alturaHeader);

        if (alturaMain < alturaHeader) {
            alert("test");
            $('.main').css({'min-height': alturaHeader });
        }
    }); 
});
```

any suggestions ?

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JWf7u/
Thanks.

Comment: Try to duplicate the issue in http://jsfiddle.net/. Include only the relevant HTML and CSS.

Comment: @iambriansreed ok, done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is you [fiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/JWf7u/) You should update the height of div everytime it changes.

```
    var alturaHeader = $('header').height();
    var alturaMain = $('.main').height();

    $('button').click(function(){
        $('header').height(function(index, height){
            return (height + 50);
        });

        alturaHeader = $('header').height()
        if (alturaMain < alturaHeader) {
            $('.main').css({'min-height': alturaHeader });
        }
    });
```

Comment: it's a tag, not a class in another tag.

Answer (score 0):

why dont u use the css property **height:100%** for main (child) div..

check the below

```
$(function () {
    var alturaHeader = $('.header').height();
    var alturaMain = $('.main').height();

    $('button').click(function(){
        $('.header').height(function(index, height){
            return (height + 50);
        });
       // below is not required we are using css to handle this
       /*
        console.log(alturaHeader);

        if (alturaMain < alturaHeader) {
            alert("test");
            $('.main').css({'min-height': alturaHeader });
        }
        */
    }); 
});
```

--CSS--

```
.header
{
    border:1px solid black;
}
.main
{
    border:1px solid red;
    height:100%;
}
```

**heigth:100%** it will do what u want check the below fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/7fkp9/

**remember as we have border right now so they dont have the same height.. it will very by 2 pixel.. for exact same height dont use the border property or set the border-size to zero(0) pixel**

Comment: can u please let me know why **-1**

Comment: you didnt get the point. They wont have always the same height... They will have the same height ONLY when header is bigger than main.

Comment: ok so u mean they are not in parent-child relationship. is it so??